# Full Width Slideshow Above Content

Tags: wordpress, slideshow

I am using a wordpress version of Supersized. My issue is that I wish to have this nice resizable full-width image gallery but be able to place the content below. An example of how I wish it to perform here; http://www.pedinilondon.co.uk/ They are using the non-wordpress version so are easily able to break it out of the template.

Is it simply a case of CSS or div manipulation or am I running into a brick wall with this? Should I be using a different knd of slideshow to achieve what I want?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you want sounds like fluid images (responsive design), which there seems to be a plug-in for that.  http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-fluid-images/faq/